# debuggung source map load issues with visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

So I have been working on an angular 1.x app using visual studio and Typescript when I noticed I was getting this error

```
SourceMap http://localhost:3131/Components/bbApp.js.map read failed: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0..'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Sourcemap (http://localhost:3131/Components/account/account.js)'.
```

Trying to google that error or many versions of it hasn't produced anything useful. My question is how do you debug something like this and figure out what is causing it to complain when it loads?

Comment: I bet you have rewrite/redirect rule in web.config or somewhere else - when *.js.map is requested server returns root page instead (html). To confirm - try to load http://localhost:3131/Components/bbApp.js.map directly and see what you get

Comment: Nope - I still am seeing the error in the output of VS but here is the first part of what I see when I load that page {"version":3,"file":"bbApp.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["bbApp.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA,IAAO,KAAK - Fiddler also sees this and can tell it's JSON i.e. I click the JSON tab and format's is nicely.